# how to break results inside a variable into lines and do foreach for each line

Tags: jquery

Hello I'm coding a searching system via Ajax abit different one and I have a problem, is it possible to break data fetch through ajax and do **foreach** for each line in javascript?

Here I send the user's search query to a php file which gives back results from database for that query..

```
    $.post("rpc.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data) { 


        $('#suggestions').html(data); // Fill the suggestions div
    });
```

so data coming from php file is stored inside **data** variable as a set but line by line,like example..

```
Google helps us
Facebook is a social network
Stackoverflow is the best
Im on twitter
```

but

```
$('#suggestions').html(data);
```

will directly put all the things inside **data** to suggestions html element..

I want to know is it possible to break things inside **data** to lines and do **foreach** for each line...

Comment: no it just contain all the results as one

Comment: What's the line separator? `\n`?

Comment: results come as html but line by line, separator is </br>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the `data` by `<br />`, and then iterate over the resulting lines array:

```
var lines = data.split("<br />");
var $suggestions = $("#suggestions");
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
  var line = lines[i];
  // ...
}
```

Comment: yeah this one helped me...I did some changes myself to this code, i really wanted to get results one by one by breaking results into lines and put them inside many div's in order using foreach instead of suggestions div at one..now i can do by developing this code..thnx

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the line breaks so that the rendered html is all in a single line:

```
$('#suggestions').html( data.toString().replace(/\<br \/\>/g, ' ') );
```

[**Working demo of this code**](http://jsfiddle.net/KxFQW/)

Note that using this regex replace is more efficient than doing several DOM manipulation operations or string concatenations.

---

For completeness, this is also possible with a for loop, though less efficient and unnecessary here:

```
var arr = data.toString().split("<br />");
var text = '';

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
    text += ' ' + arr[i];
}

$('#suggestions').html( text );
```

Comment: nope data variable contains all the html stuff but line by line and i didnt need to remove breaks, all i needed was display line by line instead whole html stuff.. thnks nbrooks..

Comment: @user1640668 np, misunderstood your q -- glad it was helpful in part at least

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `split` and `for` to do this:

```
$.post("rpc.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data) { 
    var lines = data.split("\n");
    for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        // Do something with each line
    }
});
```

You might also want to try sending the data as a JSON array and then use `$.getJSON` to process it on the client.